# How to activate JavaScript before the next page starts to load?

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I want to make a loading screen that appears when someone submits a Django form. Here's some example code:

forms.py

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    example_field = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
```

index.html

```
<style>
    .overlay {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        z-index: 5000;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 20%;
    }
</style>
<form action="example_form">
    {% for each in example_form %}
        {{ each.label_tag }}
        {{ each  }}
    {% endif %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="action" value="submit">submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function ShowLoading() {
            $(".overlay").show();
        }

        $("button[type='submit']").on("click", ShowLoading)
      })
</script>
```

This code successfully has a loading screen appear when the submit button is clicked and before the next page loads. However, the problem comes when  you don't enter anything in it's single required field but click on submit anyway. What happens is that a tooltip that tells the user to enter an input will appear, but the loading screen will appear anyway even though it's not actually loading another page. This is because it activates by click and not whether or not the next page starts loading.

What I want is instead of the JavaScript activating on button click, I want it to activate when the next page is loading but before the next page actually starts to appear. Is there a way for JavaScript to sense this sort of thing?

Comment: If its a simple form like that, why not validate if the form is empty before showing overlay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$("button[type='submit']").on("click", ShowLoading)
```

with

```
$("form").on("submit",ShowLoading);
```